# Appending a string to Compile Output pane of Qt Creator?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

Currently I'm developing my own plugin for Qt Creator. Now I need to dump an output to Compile Output pane of Qt Creator.
One way was creating new build step but it was not what I was looking for.
Any Idea is welcome.